# Gensim doc2vec, how to get the value of loss function in each step

Tags: nlp, gensim, doc2vec

```py
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from random import shuffle
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

tagged_data = []
clas = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3']
for cla in clas:
  with open(f'../data/jieba/{cla}train.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')as f:
    i = 0
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
      tagged_data.append(TaggedDocument(words=line.split(' ')[:-1], tags=[cla + str(i)]))
      i += 1

num_doc = len(tagged_data)
shuffle(tagged_data)

model = Doc2Vec(dm=1, vector_size=128, window=5, alpha=0.01, min_alpha=0.0001, max_vocab_size=100000, sample=1e-5, workers=4, epochs=3, hs=1, dm_mean=1)
model.build_vocab(tagged_data)
model.train(documents=tagged_data, epochs=model.epochs, total_examples=num_doc)
model.save("d2v.model")
```

The above is my code and the output is like

```
2019-05-11 01:11:48,177 : INFO : EPOCH 1 - PROGRESS: at 3.64% examples, 307751 words/s, in_qsize 7, out_qsize 0
2019-05-11 01:11:49,195 : INFO : EPOCH 1 - PROGRESS: at 7.63% examples, 316010 words/s, in_qsize 7, out_qsize 0
2019-05-11 01:11:50,196 : INFO : EPOCH 1 - PROGRESS: at 11.44% examples, 316465 words/s, in_qsize 8, out_qsize 0
```

How to get the value of loss function in each step so I can visualize it?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I am looking in the same problem now

Comment: You can look in this function: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.get_latest_training_loss. However, for me it is not working

Answer (score 1):

**Gensims' `Doc2Vec`, at least through versions 3.8.3 (and May 2020), doesn't have the `compute_loss` functionality that was contributed for `Word2Vec` (but has always been a bit buggy and incomplete).**

(Gensim's `Word2Vec` includes an initialization parameter `compute_loss` which, if `True`, cause the model to keep a running total of loss during training which can then be requested via `get_training_loss()`. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec

But, this training-loss reporting is a newish feature that doesn't quite yet work the way most people expect.

For example, at least through gensim 3.8.3 (May 2020), you can just retrieve the total loss since the last call to `train()` (across multiple epochs). And, in longer training runs, precision problems with the chosen internal representation cause loss tallying to eventually stop. Some [pending changes](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2135) may eventually fix that, to be just the loss for one training epoch.

If you want to sample the loss repeatedly, you'll either need to call `train()` multiple times (manually managing the epochs/alpha per call), which is very error-prone, or make use of the [callbacks](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/callbacks.html#gensim.models.callbacks.CallbackAny2Vec) capability to run a function you specify at certain points in the training.)

(Separately: you may not want to use such a small `max_vocab_size=100000` to limit your model's final vocabulary. That setting will prevent the initial vocabulary survey from *ever* tracking more than 100000 words – discarding many tallies any time that threshold is reached, resulting in a final vocabulary that could be far less than 100000 and wouldn't necessarily include the 100000 most-common words. If memory use during that initial survey is a concern, it's proper to use a generous `max_vocab_size`, much larger than the final count you'd like, that prevents the tally from using all memory. Using `max_final_vocab` and/or `min_count` will precisely limit the vocabulary at the end of the survey, without any premature discarding.)

Comment: Is the get_training_loss() method available for Doc2Vec? From what I see on the [GitHub disscussions](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/999#issuecomment-368429199), that was only implemented for Word2Vec.

Comment: I'm not sure about `get_training_loss()` on `Doc2Vec`, but the classes share enough code it might work. What happens when you try it?

Comment: I get 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'get_training_loss'.
A quick look at doc2vec.py verifies that that method isn't implemented there.